# embedding multiple Twitter buttons in one page?

Tags: drupal, twitter, drupal-6, twitter-button

I'm using Drupal and I have a list of items (View with many nodes) in one page.

I want to add a Twitter button for each of these items in the list, however I'm only able to create a tweet button for the page and not for each item

http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Any idea how to embed multiple Twitter buttons in one page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue when i wanted to tweet dynamic ajax text but could work out how to just tweet specific text or in your case, a list item. Follow this tutorial: http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/dynamic-jquery-twitter-status/

Comment: @benhowdle89 hey, in the demo you passed, if I'm not wrong, they always use the same url for all snippets loaded with ajax. I actually would like to generate a different url for each article of the list, otherwise it doesn't work. Right ?

Comment: Absolutely, but on this line: window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=' + url + '...http://bit.ly/h2yqcx', 'Tweet', 'width=750,height=500 the bit.ly url is the url of my blog post, you could jQuery/javascript to change this to a variable containing your unique urls

Comment: @benhowdle89 Thanks, I think I can actually solve it by generating my url and using "#" selector on a specific div inside my page. What about facebook button?

Comment: Similar to my code but this: http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-create-your-one-facebook-share-url/

Comment: @benhowdle89 ok cool. One last thing: do you maybe know where I can get a facebook "Share" button sprite ? I mean multiple button status shots in one single picture

Comment: Googled around, cant really find one, you will have to hit Photoshop :)